# Вычисление периметра и площади треугольника по заданным координатам

Tags: c#

Проблема заключается в выводе переменной. Area выводится, а second_area(это часть формулы area) нет. Возможно я неправильно нахожу максимум числа(

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите x вершины A:");
double first_apex_of_A = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите y вершины A:");
double second_apex_of_A = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите x вершины B:");
double first_apex_of_B = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите y вершины B:");
double second_apex_of_B = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите x вершины C:");
double first_apex_of_C = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите y вершины C:");
double second_apex_of_C = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
double distance_of_AB;
double distance_of_AC;
double distance_of_BC;
double periemetr;
double area;
double second_area;

distance_of_AB = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((first_apex_of_B - first_apex_of_A), 2) + 
  Math.Pow((second_apex_of_B - second_apex_of_A), 2)));
distance_of_AC = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((first_apex_of_C - first_apex_of_A), 2) + 
  Math.Pow((second_apex_of_C - second_apex_of_A), 2)));
distance_of_BC = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((first_apex_of_B - first_apex_of_C), 2) +
  Math.Pow((second_apex_of_B - second_apex_of_C), 2)));
periemetr = distance_of_AB + distance_of_AC + distance_of_BC;
area = ((first_apex_of_B - first_apex_of_A)*(second_apex_of_C-second_apex_of_A))-
  ((first_apex_of_C-first_apex_of_A)*(second_apex_of_B-second_apex_of_A));
//here!
second_area = (1 / 2) * (Math.Max(-area,area));
Console.WriteLine($"Периметр треугольника равен: {periemetr:#.##}\nПлощадь треугольника равна {second_area:#.##}");
```

Comment: Что делает этот код? И что должен делать?

Comment: Уберите ``:#.##`` в `Console.WriteLine()` и будет выводиться

Comment: Вычисляет периметр и площадь треугольника по заданным координатам. Да, по всей видимости я облажался, все решилось, всего лишь все из-за #, спасибо AlAvenger за наводку!